# How to click on every link in the navbar without getting StaleElementException [Python] [Selenium]

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Task:** I want to click on every link in the navbar

**Key Points:**

- The navbar is the same across different pages.
- Clicking on a link redirects me to another website.

**My current approach:** All Navbar links have the "nav-item" class. First I find all elements which have the nav-item class and store them in an array. My problem arises when I click on a single link, I get redirected to another page. This in turn causes all the other elements in the array to get "stale".

To solve this, I thought of getting the xpath of each element stored in the array and the loop over the xpaths array to click every button. This way I'm freshly locating each and every link and then clicking on them. However, I can't find a way to get the xpath of an already located element in Selenium.

How can I avoid the StaleExceptionError or get the XPATH of an already located element?

Comment: Share the the HTML in the text form or the URL of the page and also share the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: Can't disclose the target website.